# Sync RAM related

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I am trying to simulate the following code for an synchronous ram in Verilog.

When I am trying to write in a specific address, **dataOut** is not coming the way I was expecting. It is skipping 1 address while reading data in the specified address.

[image]

Can anyone tell me the problem?

Here is GtkWave simulation result:

[image]

```
module ram 
  # (parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 4,
     parameter DATA_WIDTH = 10,
     parameter DEPTH = 1 <<  ADDR_WIDTH
    )
  
  (     input                   clk,
        input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0]  addr,
        input [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  dataIn,
        input                   enable,
        input                   write,
        input                   read,
      input           resetRam, 
      output[DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  dataOut  
  );
  
  reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  tmp_data;
  reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  mem [DEPTH-1:0];

  //reset 
  always @(posedge clk) begin 
    if(enable & resetRam) begin
      for (integer i = 0; i < 2**ADDR_WIDTH; i = i + 1)
      begin
        mem[i] = {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
      end
    end
  end
  
  //write
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (enable & write & !read)
      mem[addr] <= dataIn;
  end
  
  //read
  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (enable & !write & read)
        tmp_data <= mem[addr];
  end
  
  assign dataOut = enable & read & !write ? tmp_data : 'hz || enable & resetRam ? 10'b0 : 'hz;
  
endmodule

module ram_tb;
  parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 4;
  parameter DATA_WIDTH = 10;
  parameter DEPTH = 1 << ADDR_WIDTH;
  
  reg clk;
  reg enable;
  reg write;
  reg read;
  reg resetRam;
  reg [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] addr;
  wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] dataIn;
  wire [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] dataOut;
  reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] tb_data;
  
  ram #(.DATA_WIDTH(DATA_WIDTH)) iram(
                          .clk(clk),
                            .addr(addr),
                            .dataIn(dataIn),
                            .enable(enable),
                                      .write(write),
                                      .read(read),
                          .resetRam(resetRam),
                          .dataOut(dataOut)
                         );
  
  
  always #10 clk = ~clk;
  assign dataIn = !read ? tb_data : 'hz ;
  
  
  initial begin
    $monitor("addrs = %b resetRam=%b Write = %b  read=%b dataIn = %b dataOut = %b", addr,resetRam,write,read,dataIn,dataOut);
    $dumpfile("ram_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0,ram_tb);

    {clk, enable, write, addr, tb_data, read,resetRam} <= 0;
    


    // //writing all the adrress with random value
    // for (integer i = 0; i < DEPTH; i= i+1) begin
    //  @(posedge clk) addr <= i; write = 1; enable =1; read = 0; tb_data <= $random;
    // end


    // //reading them
    // for (integer i = 0; i < DEPTH; i= i+1) begin
    //  @(posedge clk) addr = i; write = 0; enable = 1; read = 1;
    // end


     //Writing at specific address
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b1000; write = 1; enable =1; read = 0; tb_data <= $random;
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b1111; write = 1; enable =1; read = 0; tb_data <= $random;
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b1001; write = 1; enable =1; read = 0; tb_data <= $random;
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b0001; write = 1; enable =1; read = 0; tb_data <= $random;  

    

    //reading them
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b1000;write = 0; enable =1; read = 1;
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b1111;write = 0; enable =1; read = 1;
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b1001;write = 0; enable =1; read = 1;
    @(posedge clk) addr = 4'b0001;write = 0; enable =1; read = 1;
    

    

    // //reset memory
    // for (integer i = 0; i < DEPTH; i= i+1) begin
    //  repeat (1) @(posedge clk) addr <= i; enable <= 1; resetRam <=1;
    // end


    
    #200 $finish;
  end
endmodule

//iverilog -o ram_tb.vpp ram.v
//vvp ram_tb.vpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition.  You should use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) in your design and testbench for all synchronous signals.

In the design, change:

```
    mem[i] = {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
```

to:

```
    mem[i] <= {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
```

In the testbench, use:

```
 //Writing at specific address
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b1000; write <= 1; enable <=1; read <= 0; tb_data <= $random;
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b1111; write <= 1; enable <=1; read <= 0; tb_data <= $random;
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b1001; write <= 1; enable <=1; read <= 0; tb_data <= $random;
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b0001; write <= 1; enable <=1; read <= 0; tb_data <= $random;  

//reading them
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b1000;write <= 0; enable <=1; read <= 1;
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b1111;write <= 0; enable <=1; read <= 1;
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b1001;write <= 0; enable <=1; read <= 1;
@(posedge clk) addr <= 4'b0001;write <= 0; enable <=1; read <= 1;
```

With the above changes, I get your expected output with `iverilog` on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/U7Qd).